# How to print the predicted 'y' or 'output' matrix in this TensorFlow code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a training model in TensorFlow (see below code).

My cumulative 'Test Accuracy' is showing: 0.92357 after training my model and I want to check it to be sure I didn't mess something up.

How do I print a predicted output matrix or 'y' after I train the model given the code I have below?

```
# x will be the input matrix flattened (28x29)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 812])

# Define the weights (initial value doesn't matter since these will be learned)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([812, 812], minval=0, dtype=tf.float32))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([812], minval=0, dtype=tf.float32))

# Predict output matrix
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

# Actual output matrix from the training set
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 812])

# Calculate loss and optimize
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.025).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

a, b = get_batch()
train_len = len(a)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_, y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# Training
for i in range(train_len):
    batch_xs = a[i]
    batch_ys = b[i]
    _, loss, acc = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    print("Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + " Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))

# Test trained model
cumulative_accuracy = 0.0
for i in range(train_len):
    acc_batch_xs = a[i]
    acc_batch_ys = b[i]
    cumulative_accuracy += accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: acc_batch_xs, y_: acc_batch_ys})
print("Test Accuracy= {}".format(cumulative_accuracy / train_len))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of any tensor object can be obtained by using

```
tensorFlowObject.eval()
```

Hence, you can use `y.eval()` to get the value of `y`